# Permalink issue with Wordpress Site at domain root and another Wordpress Site in a Subfolder

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, directory, domain

If you look at my site: https://alphahedron.com/

You will see a functioning wordpress site (although not configured yet).

If you go to one of my subfolder sites: https://alphahedron.com/game/lurkzero/

You will see the lurk zero wordpress main page successfully.

However, if you click on the “Login” link on the right, the browser navigates to:
https://alphahedron.com/game/lurkzero/login/

Which (I’m guessing) would normally be processed by the LurkZero wordpress, however, that path is instead considered as part of the Alphahedron wordpress (probably assumed to be a permalink of alphahedron).

I’ve been searching the web for a solution. Modifying .htaccess might be difficult if not impossible.

I’m wondering if there is a plugin that restricts usage of certain paths of permalinks? Or some other solution?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: You're looking at the 404 template for the site. You can change that, but it's going to be the same site-wide unless you build your own custom functionality.

Comment: https://alphahedron.com/game/lurkzero/login/ normally resolves to https://alphahedron.com/game/lurkzero/wp-admin/ I believe that you're right, with a wordpress site at root, the 404 template resolves first.